# Using Intent.createChooser() works fine without FileProvider on Nougat

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I noticed interesting thing. When I send file to another app by using my own intent without using FileProvider:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sendIntent.setType("image/gif");
    sendIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS;
    sendIntent.setFlags(flags);
```

on Nougat devices app crashes.
But if I use next code:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("image/gif");
    String titleForChooser = getString(R.string.app_chooser_title);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS;
    sendIntent.setFlags(flags);
    Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, titleForChooser);
```

On Nougat it works fine except FB Messenger and WhatsApp. Somebody know answer "Why?"? Could you please explain me?

Comment: I think you should start using [Storage access framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

Comment: @azizbekian How it can help me?